# Where to store images on a filesystem on webserver

Tags: mysql, database, image

Where exactly do I store images on a webserver if not in my MySQL database? I've been told that storing images as a BLOB in a DB is bad practice.

Also, how do I store references to these images in a DB? If I have a food_items table, can the table look like this?

Food Items

Id | Name | Description | Price | ImageURL

1 | chicken | tasty | 100 | www.myurl.com/folderwithimages/image.jpg ??

Thanks

Comment: You should either store the full url including the http:// or the absolute path from the document root (/folderwithimage/image.jpg). But yes it's a database, you can put whatever you want in it.

Comment: How about on a CDN?  They offer all sorts of caching and geo-location optimized stuff, and you won't bog down your web server handling static files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a web server, I would highly recommend you put the image into S3.  Here's some documentation regarding [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend storing only the image name in the database, and keeping all the images in /yoursiteroot/folderwithimages.

That table looks good, but I wouldn't recommend storing the full URL in case you want to change the path or URL of the images in the future.

Comment: ok so you guys all are saying to use a relative URL, so how do I finish concatenating the URL? as in adding myurl.com/mysiteroot/folderwithimages. Where does the myurl.com part come in? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Store images in a /images folder in the filesystem on the webserver

In your database do not store the full URL to the image. Store a relative URL to the image so if your domain changes you don't have to update the database again.

/images/image.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding using the db to store images is a good practice, keeping the images in the db not only slows down your db performance it also increases it size and backups, if you are using cloud service  then there is also the costs issue.

Use S3 or Yahoo for this purpose. The only thing left to do is for your site application to connect both this services(db and the Images service),i used [this tool](https://www.backand.com/).

Store the full path only if each image resides in a diffrent location, it make no sense storing the same data for each data entry,

Comment: use a db view to concatenate the basic url "myurl.com/mysiteroot/" and  the file name that you stored in your db, or you can use the tool i suggested , you just need a few configurations.